# How can i check the checkbox in cucumber scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I have the html source:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input checked="checked" class="chb_tester" id="user_role_ids_" name="user[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <span class="role_item_text">Tester</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can i check this checkbox in my cucumber scenario?

Comment: What are you using to drive the browser?  Capybara?  Webrat?

Comment: check http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off before writing your next cucumber scenarios

Comment: Thanks for link. Very useful article will do all this way. But i've not understood now - where i should place my modules? In which file/dir?

Comment: Answer on first comment: I use Capybara

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Capybara and RSpec:

To check it:

```
check('#user_role_ids_')
```

To verify that it's checked:

```
find('#user_role_ids_').should be_checked
```

Comment: I've tried to find a checkbox with xpath. Xpath is correct, but everytime i getting this error: undefined method `to_xpath' for #<Capybara::Element tag="input"> (NoMethodError)

Comment: it should be `check("user[role_ids][]")`

Answer (score 1):

**#used to check that a checkbox is checked**

```
Then /^the "([^"]*)" checkbox should be checked$/ do |id|
  find_field(id)[:value].should eq "true" 
end
```

***And use it for Uncheck also by making assertion as false***

Answer (score 1):

Another way to check your checkbox is:

```
# When I select checkbox "report_type_summary"
When(/^I select checkbox "(.*?)"$/) do |cb|
  check(cb)
end
```

You can only select a checkbox name which is used for finding and checking the element. You can check [this article](https://kolosek.com/cucumber-cheat-sheet/) for more details.